# Steam Top 10 Games by Player Count API Call

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I want to create a simple Swift app that lists the current most popular games on Steam.

I can't find anywhere with this API call listed. steamdb.info lists this info but I can't find a way to emulate this.

Comment: There is no such API call directly from steam. SteamDB calls the player count for every single game on steam and then aggregates this to a popular games list. Same does SteamSpy as suggested by @Mattimat's answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://steamspy.com/api.php might be helpful.

For example top 100 all time: https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=top100forever 
or 
top 100 last 2 weeks: https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=top100in2weeks

It also shows useful information such as player count.